# How to get specific integer value from array?

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla, virtuemart

Here is the code

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT order_id FROM orders WHERE customer_number = '".$i."' AND created_on = '".$date."'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $dbz->loadObjectList();
print_r($rows);
```

The output is 
`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [virtuemart_order_id] => 549 ) )`

I want to get only `549` as output? What is the possible solution.

Note foreach() doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
    $rows[0]->virtuemart_order_id;
```

Comment: @WaqasKhan : Welcome bro! is it acceptable answer then please accept.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use another function to load your data. Like:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT order_id FROM orders WHERE customer_number = '".$i."' AND created_on = '".$date."'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$order_id = $dbz->loadResult();
echo $order_id;
```

Check the joomla API documentation to find the right API-calls depending on what you need to do: http://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/classes/JDatabase.html